# JOLT split and array data

Tags: arrays, json, transactions, jolt

I have a JSON like this

```json
[
  {
    "MasterUrl": "https://$$$$/exodus2022/player.aspx",
    "Programme": [
      {
        "Retirement": "2022",
        "Current Team": "Bulls",
        "Previous Team 1": "NA",
        "Previous Team 2": "NA",
        "Previous Team 3": "NA"
      },
      {
        "Retirement": "2020",
        "Current Team": "Celtics",
        "Previous Team 1": "NA",
        "Previous Team 2": "NA",
        "Previous Team 3": "NA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MasterUrl": "https://$$$$/risen2022/player.aspx",
    "Programme": [
      {
        "Current Team": "Heat",
        "Current Location": "Miami",
        "Previous Team 1": "NA",
        "Previous Team 2": "NA",
        "Previous Team 3": "NA"
      },
      {
        "Current Team": "Cavalliers",
        "Current Location": "Texas",
        "Previous Team 1": "NA",
        "Previous Team 2": "NA",
        "Previous Team 3": "NA"
      },
      {
        "Current Team": "Pistons",
        "Current Location": "New York",
        "Previous Team 1": "NA",
        "Previous Team 2": "NA",
        "Previous Team 3": "NA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I need to split the information into 2 arrays, one for the ones under the `@exodus2022` Masterurl and the other for the `@risen2022` Masterurl. Also, I need to remove the `player.aspx` from both the urls and the previous team data.

The result should be something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Exodus2022": [
      {
        "MasterUrl": "https://$$$$/exodus2022",
        "Programme": [
          {
            "Retirement": "2022",
            "Current Team": "Bulls"
          },
          {
            "Retirement": "2020",
            "Current Team": "Celtics"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Risen2022": [
      {
        "MasterUrl": "https://$$$$/risen2022",
        "Programme": [
          {
            "Current Team": "HEAT",
            "Current Location": "Miami"
          },
          {
            "Current Team": "Cavalliers",
            "Current Location": "Texas"
          },
          {
            "Current Team": "Pistons",
            "Current Location": "New York"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can this transformation be done with a JOLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MasterUrl": "=split('/player.aspx', @(1,MasterUrl))",
        "MasterUr*": "=lastElement"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=split('https://\\$\\$\\$\\$/', @(1,MasterUrl))",
        "ke*": "=lastElement"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=split('', @(1,key))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": {
          "[0]": "=toUpper(@(0))"
        },
        "ke*": "=join('',@0)"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MasterUrl|Programme": "[&1].@(1,key).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Programme": {
            "*": {
              "Previous*": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Without `lastElement`**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MasterUrl": "=split('/player.aspx', @(1,MasterUrl))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "MasterUrl": {
          "0": "[&2].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=split('https://\\$\\$\\$\\$/', @(1,MasterUrl))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "key": {
          "1": "[&2].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=split('', @(1,key))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": {
          "[0]": "=toUpper(@(0))"
        },
        "ke*": "=join('',@0)"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MasterUrl|Programme": "[&1].@(1,key).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Programme": {
            "*": {
              "Previous*": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The version of apache that i'm using doesn't support lastElement as a resource, is there any other way to do this?